# What effect do the 'Hungryiness' and 'thirst4Dew' stats have?

Tags: montage-parody-the-game

**Disclaimer:** (Yes, this is a [real game](http://www.gameoftheyear420blazeit.com/))

---

In the Montage parody game (*GAME OF THE YEAR: 420BLAZEIT vs. xxXilluminatiXxx [wow/10 #rekt edition] Montage Parody The Game*) the stats shown in the top right of the screenshot below seem to tick up as you move around, and can be reset to 0 by picking up the Doritos bags & Dew cans respectively. Picking up these items also restores health.

But I haven't seen any effect (negative or otherwise) from the stats alone.

Do they have an effect in-game?

[image: Screenshot in-game showing the 'hungryiness' and 'thirst4Dew' stars]

Comment: I also considered `[gameoftheyear-420blazeit]` for the tag, but opted for the safer option

Comment: What the hell is this...

Comment: @Anto - lol. Only the most dank MLG Montage video game ever created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decompiled the game source code, and it shows that if your hunger (or thirst) "points" are at 100, it applies 5 "starve" (or thirst) damage every 3 seconds. These can both apply at the same time.

```
public float starveInterval = 3f; 
public float starveAmt = -5f;


if (lastHungerTime + hungerInterval < Time.time) 
    UpdateHunger(1f); 

if (hungerPoints == maxHungerPoints && lastStarveTime + starveInterval < Time.time && hitPoints > 0.0) 
{ 
    HealPlayer(starveAmt); 
    (Instantiate(painFadeObj) as GameObject).GetComponent<PainFade>().FadeIn(PainColor, painTexture, 0.75f); 
    if (hitPoints < 1.0) 
        SendMessage("Die"); 
    timeLastDamaged = Time.time; lastStarveTime = Time.time; 
}
```

Comment: Despite it saying "HealPlayer", it's actually passing through a negative amount - `starveAmt` - which applies negative "healing" - damage.